# is it a proper way to do php update?

Tags: php, conditional-statements

here with the updated core. Is it a proper way to do it?
I try to do Prepared Statements by following the tutorial from the web, but not working well.

```
$Enrolsql = "Select * FROM Enrol WHERE ActivityID=$activityid AND UserPhone=$userPhone AND UseUp=1";

$Enrolresult = $conn->query($Enrolsql);
if ($Enrolresult->num_rows > 0) {

    $ssql = "UPDATE Enrol SET UseUp=0 WHERE ActivityID=$activityid";
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $ssql)) {
        echo "+1+"; //successfully Used.
    } else {
        echo "+2+"; // System Error.
    }
} else {
    echo "+0+"; // Coupon is not Vaild
}

$conn->close();
```

Database Table info:

[image]

Comment: That just means that your query executed successfully. Check the number of affected rows to see what has happened. And you should read up on sql injection.

Comment: Your if loop has to do with query execution not valid/invalid values.

Comment: Before diving into your problem, you should visiot http://bobby-tables.com and learn about SQL injection. Actually your code is really vulnerable and not save at all. Your whole database can be hacked in a few seconds, without any need of deeper knowledge of your system. NEVER put in userinputs directly in queries. Use prepared statements instead. You can learn anything about prepared statements and how to use them on bobby-tables.com - Its a really easy topic and the code is changed in 2 minutes. I highly recommend you to do this.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I updated my code. Is it the proper way to do it?

Comment: You should also indent your code properly, it will make your life easier in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php,

`mysqli_query` Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

Given that you are running an UPDATE, and assuming the update didn't fail (just had no effect) you will be getting back `TRUE` hence you are printing `+1+`

Comment: @EricChong If this is helpful, please can you consider upvoting my answer or maybe marking it as the accepted answer?

Comment: @EricChong

Please can you upvote this answer if it is helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can do multiple checks here:

Check if any errors:

```
if (!mysql_error()) print 'Query executed successfully.';
```

Check affected rows:

```
if(mysql_affected_rows() || mysql_affected_rows() == 0){
    // no error
} else {
    // error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am giving you fully a long tutorial on this post. In this article, I am going to discuss Update query with HTML implementation in PHP. So let’s get started.

```html
<?php
require_once 'dbconnection.php';
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){
 $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
 $age = $_REQUEST['age'];
 $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
 $email = $_REQUEST['email'];
 $user_id=$_REQUEST['user_id'];
 $qry = mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `user` SET `name`='".$name."', `email`='".$email."',`age`='".$age."',`phone`='".$phone."' WHERE `u_id`='".$user_id."'");
 if(!$qry){
 echo "Faild to insert data in database";
 }
 else{
 $_SESSION['success'] = "Data updated Successfully";
 echo "<script>window.location.href='update.php?u_id='".$user_id."'</script>";
 }
}
?>
```